# On the behavior of critically damped oscillators

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators, dissipation

Is a critically damped oscillator always going to approach the equilibrium position faster that the same system with underdamping or overdamping for a given set of initial conditions, no matter what those conditions might be?

Comment: Do you mean "...faster that the same system with **underdamping** or overdamping"?  It doesn't make much sense to compare critical damping to critical damping.

Comment: good answers here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/686473/why-does-critical-damping-return-to-equilibrium-faster-than-overdamping

Comment: @Michael Seifert Oh I revised the question multiple and didn't notice I wrote this!

Comment: I got the answers that I was looking for, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the damped oscillator equation $$ \ddot{x} + 2 \beta \dot{x} + \omega_0^2 x = 0.$$
The decay behavior of a critically damped or underdamped oscillator is controlled by a factor of $e^{-\beta t}$.  However, the general solution for  an overdamped oscillator is
$$
x(t) = C_1 e^{-(\beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 - \omega_0^2})t} + C_2 e^{-(\beta - \sqrt{\beta^2 - \omega_0^2})t}
$$
and if we happen to pick our initial conditions so that $C_2 = 0$, then the solution will decay proportionally to $e^{-(\beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 - \omega_0^2})t}$ — faster than the critically damped or underdamped case.

Note, however, that the initial conditions have to be chosen *just so* to get this slower decay rate.  In particular, it works out that you need to have
$$
\dot{x}(0) = -(\beta + \sqrt{\beta^2 - \omega_0^2}) x(0)
$$
to get a solution where $C_2 = 0$.  Any deviation from this, no matter how slight, will result in a solution where $C_2 \neq 0$, and since the corresponding exponential decays more slowly, it will dominate the decay behavior at late times.  In other words, a generic set of initial conditions will lead to a slower decay rate than for the underdamped or critically damped case;  only for a special subset of initial conditions does the oscillator decay more quickly.